# Twig 'is same as(0.0)' for the value of 0.0 is false

Tags: floating-point, twig

In the following Twig snippet (see https://twigfiddle.com/agvgz9):

```
{{ 0.0 is same as (0.0) ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}

{{ val is same as (0.0) ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
```

the output results in the following

```
Yes

No
```

`dump(val)` outputs `float(0)`

The second expression one would expect to evaluate to `Yes`, but why is it otherwise? I would understand if this failed if, for example, `val = 0.0000000001;`, but according to dump, it's clearly not the case.

Doing a simple test in `php -a` with

```
$val = 0.0;
$echo $val === 0.0 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

results in `Yes`, which is as expected.

[image: php -a output]

Can this be considered a bug with Twig?

*Using Twig version 2.5.0, tried upgrading to 2.6.0 as well.*

Comment: It is considered otherwise because `same as` uses a typed equality and `twig`'s compiler casts `0.0` to `(int)0`

Comment: It definitely does something, however `{{ val is same as (0) ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}` also evaluates to `No` / `false`, and according to `dump(val)` it is `float(0)`

Comment: You're probably right about the `(int)0`, the cast possibly happens just before the value is being evaluation / output. So `dump(val)` outputs the context as is, before it is cast or sanitised for output.

Comment: You can check the compiled source of your `twigfiddle` to verify my comment btw

Comment: `echo ((((isset($context["val"]) || array_key_exists("val", $context) ? $context["val"] : (function () { throw new Twig_Error_Runtime('Variable "val" does not exist.', 3, $this->source); })()) === 0)) ? ("Yes") : ("No"));`

Comment: also I meant `twig` compiles the literal `0.0` to `0` (`dump(0.0)` is `(int)0`) and not the variable `val`

Comment: Thanks so much, I see now.

Comment: This breaks the whole idea of strict equality. I think the behaviour should be the same as PHP, maybe there are some other reasons for Twig changing float(0) to int(0).

Comment: You could open an issue on github for this I guess - I'm guessing you'll find your answer over there

Comment: Created an issue on GitHub, let's see if they decide whether it's a bug or a feature. https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2788